# Implementing multiple view models

Tags: apex, inheritance

I have the following scenario where I'm trying to use view models which will be accessed in the Visualforce page from various controller, in order to build the various UIs.

```
interface IOne {
    void setOne();
}
interface ITwo {
    void setTwo();
}

public class ViewModel implements IOne,ITwo
{
    String valueOne;
    String valueTwo;

    public void setOne(String value) {
        valueOne = value;
    }

    public void setTwo(String value) {
        valueTwo = value;
    }
}

public class ServiceOne
{
    public void static ResolveOne(IOne value)
    {
        value.setOne('1');
    }
}

public class ServiceTwo
{
    public void static ResolveTwo(ITwo value)
    {
        value.setTwo('2');
    }
}
```

The view model would be instantiated in the controller and it will be passed to the various service which will populate it with the data, from Salesforce or external call. As an argument to the resolve methods I have the various interface that service is responsible to populate, which means that once inside the method the service will only have access to the correct method from the interface.

The problem is when I try to add another view model, which might use the same methods `setOne()` and `setTwo()`, but also has an extra method on `interfaceOne`, let's say `setThree()`. I would then need to implement the added method into the first view model as well as in the second view model which will result in duplicating the code.

The question is how to have a common object where all the common methods are implemented and have multiple view models, which have access to the common methods but also defining there own methods

Hope I've been clear in my question and also tell me if I'm over-engineering this.

Comment: Ha, no it's not super clear and yes you may be over-engineering. If you add `setThree` on `IOne`, then you would have to implement it on `ViewModel`, then probably would want to also on `ServiceOne`? Not sure what the gap is.

Comment: Yes, that's correct I will use setThree in ServiceOne. So if you imagine I create another view model called it ViewModelTwo which will implement IOne and ITwo, but ViewModelTwo will not need to have access to setThree, it should be optional as it's specific to ViewModel. I guess what I'm trying to do is to limit the duplication in the code, having to implement setOne, setTwo, setThree in every ViewModel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add optional methods, you may want to use an `abstract class`. You can define an empty `virtual` method that you only `override` when you want it to be defined.

```
public interface IOne
{
    void setOne();
    void setThree();
}
public interface ITwo
{
    void setTwo();
}

public abstract class AbstractViewModel implements IOne, ITwo
{
    String valueOne;
    String valueTwo;
    String valueThree;
    public void setOne(String value)
    {
        valueOne = value;
    }
    public void setTwo(String value)
    {
        valueTwo = value;
    }
    public virtual void setThree(String value) { }
}
```

Then you would need to extend it.

```
public class ViewModelOne extends AbstractViewModel implements IOne, ITwo
{
    public override void setThree(String value)
    {
        valueThree = value;
    }
}

public class ViewModelTwo extends AbstractViewModel implements IOne, ITwo
{
    // already has everything you need
}
```

Now you can do:

```
ViewModelOne model1 = new ViewModelOne();
model1.setOne('1');
model1.setTwo('2');
model1.setThree('3');

ViewModelTwo model2 = new ViewModel();
model2.setOne('1');
model2.setTwo('2');
model2.setThree('3'); // doesn't actually do anything
```

Comment: When the ViewModelTwo implements IOne and ITwo don't you need to define setThree(), assuming it exists on IOne interface ? That means that I define the method in ViewModelTwo without needing it, thus creating duplication. I was trying to do the same pattern as you, with the abstract class, but I still end in duplicating the code.

Comment: Okay, I think I get what you are going for better...changed it up a bit.

Comment: Hmm, I like it ! ... I will have to test it tomorrow as I will shortly have to go home and I will let you know. Thank you for now!

Comment: It worked, the only disadvantage that I see is you might have certain methods empty and the calling code has the responsibility to know what to call and what not to call.

Comment: That seems somewhat inherent in what you are looking for. You could throw an exception in those methods instead of leaving them empty...then you would only be able to call them when they are defined.